# Internal speaker sound at login screen - but not after login (only external speakers work)?

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

Sound plays (drum roll) at login screen.
In Ubuntu and Xubuntu XFCE no sound emits from the laptop speaker, but does from the external speakers.
Pulseaudio panel monitor bar dances with the sound.... but nothing heard.

A number of tests have been carried out, as listed below, and in the comments of Answer 1.
As yet nobody has come up with a method of establishing how to direct the sound to the internal speaker.

[Ubuntu MutiMedia forum suggests asking here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289715), as nobody there can identify the correct procedure to rectify this problem
All tests have been logged on that forum.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Here's the Alsa info script log:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=77747dc55bb07c3ef222dec15332bd35d5ab9aaf

Ran:

```
$ echo autospawn = no >> ~/.config/pulse/client.conf  #use ~/.pulse/client.conf on Ubuntu <= 12.10
$ killall pulseaudio
$ LANG=C pulseaudio -vvvv --log-time=1 > ~/pulseverbose.log 2>&1
```

Output: http://filebin.ca/2BYEAFV6WLpi/pulseverbosecopy.log

Ran:

```
$ pacmd
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
$ rm -r ~/.pulse*; pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
```

Other test logs:

```
pastebin.com/3nhedfx6
pastebin.com/4UVxCJXM
pastebin.com/XxbSDvRR
```

Perhaps if we could establish the sound setup at the login screen, we would see how it should be configured.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Thank you Gilles, for adding the direct link to the pulseverbose.log

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest purging the pulseaudio package.  You could remove it's files and then re-install it, if you really want to try that.

Things to check:

```
psg () { ps u -p $(pgrep "${@:--u$USER}");  }  # define a handy function

psg pulse   # see if there is a pulseaudio process running

cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params 
  # see if anything in your system has the sound device open

lsof /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
  # see what has the sound device open

pavucontrol   # a pulseaudio config gui
```

These commands are all checking the first PCM playback stream of alsa `card0`.  This is the HDA-Intel analog output, which is almost certainly what's hooked up to your speakers.

Actually, hmm, I'm not 100% sure your system has `card0` as the analog out.  It looks like `card0` is your HDMI output, and `card1` is

```
Card hw:1 'SB'/'HDA ATI SB at 0xd0440000 irq 16'
```

Try playing something back through card1.  e.g.

```
aplay -L  # choose a "device string"
aplay -vv -D hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3 foo.wav
# vs.
aplay -vv -D hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 foo.wav
```

Device sub-numbers may be different on your system.

These direct hw: devices are what pulseaudio uses as a backend.  If pulseaudio has the alsa hw device open, `aplay` won't be able to use it directly, only through `dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0` or similar (`dmix:` devices actually send data to pulseaudio to allow sharing, not directly to the device.)

`-D default` is alsa default that presumably your pulseaudio is set up to use.  PA is configurable, though.  If you need to, you can change its default output to the one that actually makes noise with `aplay`.

Sorry I didn't dig through all the stuff you said you tried, so some of this may be redundant.

One great thing about Linux is that when the high-level frontend stuff gets more confusing rather than less, or seems over-complicated, it's usually easy to poke around under the hood. :)  (dbus / systemd are exceptions to this, though.)

Comment: Thanks Peter... purge was just something to try. I'll work through your list.
TO CLARIFY: the laptop has only one jack output, to headphones.

Comment: The headphone jack can feed the ext speakers.... it always emits sound, even when the two config options are tried 'headphones' & 'speakers'.
Is config confused.... does it think 'speakers' are on an ext jack output.
IE. Login sees the int. speaker, but desktop doesn't.
it would explain why choosing speakers, still channels sound through the headphone jack.
Perhaps there should be 3 config options: Int speaker, speakers, headphones.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3nhedfx6

The above lists all the tests..... there are a lot of them.
to get many to work, I had to change dirs and names, but everything is documented.
Phew!

Comment: @Marco-UandL: Ok, looks like pulse is already set up to play through the analog-out PCM device, and it's `card1` (`SB`), `dev=0`. Maybe there's a mixer setting (`alsamixer`) to unmute the speakers, instead of just the headphones.  Try unmuting and turning up the volume on everything in `alsamixer`.  (Make sure it's controlling the correct card, by looking in the top left.)

Comment: Downloaded gnome-alsamixer. Here are the results. Sadly no success as yet, but 'eliminating possibles' is good. http://pastebin.com/4UVxCJXM

Comment: @Marco-UandL: It's normal for something to mute some mixer channels when you plug something into the headphone or mic jack.  I don't have any experience with your specific hardware, and I've already passed on all the tips and suggestions I can think of to help you find / solve the problem.

Comment: Got a response from the pulseaudio mailing list 
Suggested to try (with sound playing):

PULSE_LOG=99 pactl info

Here's the log:

http://pastebin.com/XxbSDvRR

I note that the default channel is front-left front-right.
The laptop only has a single speaker.

Could the sound be being channeled to an external speaker output that doesn't exist?

But there again..... strange that at login, the sound is channeled correctly.

If the pactl log doesn't help....
Can we check the setup at login, and compare to the 'post desktop load' setup? 

At least we would then see a working setup.

Comment: I am now looking at default.pa - "This startup script is used only if PulseAudio is started per-user (i.e. not in system mode)" i.e. this is post login..... and it attempts to autodetect hardware, then connect sink and source.....  Is this script the primary modifier of the sound system post login?.... if so perhaps this is where we should be looking?

Comment: @Marco-UandL: PA looks fine.  Your testing showed that flashplugin playing sound through PA had your sound hardware open, but otherwise it was closed, right?  Thus, PA is getting the sound to ALSA.  If there's a different ALSA device it should be using, you can try changing its config.  (e.g. with `pavucontrol`).

Comment: No Peter.... Pavucontrol was early testing, tried umpteen times. It's something else....... my personal view, is that the problem lies between the login screen (working) and the desktop (not working)...... I still believe that if we could discern how the sound system is working at login..... we would know why it is not working at desktop...... hardware detection APPEARS to be not working, because the speaker is not recognised, and no channel is directed towards it. Otherwise, it has been detected, but is being fed incorrectly...... Is it one of these two suggestions or something else?

Comment: @Marco-UandL: Probably somewhere during login, something changes mixer or pulseaudio settings.  Try `pavumeter` or something to see sound levels for output channels, to verify that audio is going *somewhere*.  What if you log in on a text console?

Comment: Also, you might just want to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  Or 15.04, to get newer software.  The next LTS is going to be 16.04, so that's still a way off.

Comment: installed pavumeter.... it's working a treat.... dancing away..... just no sound from the speaker :) ...... re upgrade.... I know... it's the final 'eject button', when all else fails...... but, before that, we clearly have sound through the system.... it's just not being directed at the internal speaker..... if only we knew how to log the audio at login..... then we'd have our answer............ maybe we as a community will fail on this one.... it won't be the first time (and not the last) ;) ..... thankfully it's not a major issue, but no sound for some people would be...... ah well... :)

Comment: @Marco-UandL: ok, if you're planning to keep 12.04 until you get rid of that hardware, then you could spend some more time debugging it.  It's almost certainly a matter of mixer settings.  There are often some obscure ones with on/off settings that control stuff like whether sound is routed to internal and external at the same time.

Comment: Maybe you could log in over ssh, and dump the alsa state.  Then go a GUI login and dump the alsa state again, and compare.  I forget the commands, but there's a save/restore pair of commands for saving mixer settings across reboots.

Comment: PA have got back to me, and want pactl list.... apparently it will tell us what we need to know....http://pastebin.com/meqqh3m7 no sound....http://pastebin.com/PnuFzQcW youtube playing.... http://pastebin.com/dgK5uFQG my noted file differences..... other issue: U&L is suggesting that this be moved to chat, to avoid extended discussion..... should I move to chat?